# 最初に読み込む背景画像の表示時間を短くしたい

Tags: javascript, jquery

jsファイルでトップページの画像ファイルだけを最初に2秒程度表示して、そこからトップページを表示していますが、
トップページの画像ファイルの表示時間を一瞬だけ(0.5秒以内)にするにはどのようにすればいいでしょうか。

```
(function($){
  
$(function() {
    
  if($.cookie("access") == undefined) {
    $(window).load(function () {
      $('.load-bg').delay(2300).fadeOut(800);
      $('.load').delay(2000).fadeOut(300);
      
      var date=new Date();
      date.setTime(date.getTime() + (1*60*60*1000));
      $.cookie('access', 'on', {expires: date});
    });
  } else {
    $('.load-bg').hide();
  }
});

})(jQuery)
```

Comment: 今現在どれくらい時間がかかっていて、それをどれくらいに短くしたいのかを具体的に明示していただいた方が、アドバイスする方もやりやすいと思います。

Comment: 質問内容に具体的な秒数を追加しました。